# ASP.NET Core app: how to get rid of "Use another service to log in." message on login page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am following along the tutorial at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

I would like to get rid of the "Use another service to log in." message that shows up on the Log In and Register pages.

[image]

All the documentation I have seen talks about adding but never removing this message.

Comment: Thank you to the below comments about modifying the login/register pages. My confusion was because those pages don't exist in the project by default. I found an article about how to override the default pages at https://damienbod.com/2018/08/07/disabling-parts-of-asp-net-core-identity/

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit the cshtml file in Areas -> Identity -> Pages -> Account -> login.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete  related code by yourself in `~\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Login.cshtml`

**Delete this code**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to log in.</h3>
            <hr />
            @{
                if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See this <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">article
                            about setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services</a>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins!)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
```

Now the `Use another service to log in` section will not show in the view.

[image]